# Can I have a Structure as member of its own structure in C?

Tags: c, performance, structure, recursive-datastructures

Can I create an instance of one structure in its own structure (recursive structure) in C (although I do of course now that this is kind of bizarre and tricky)?

Like:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct type
    {
         char name[20];
         char address[35];

         struct type;
    };

    return 0;
}
```

---

Of course, the compiler gives me the warning:

```
warning: declaration does not declare anything
```

but he/it let it pass and gives me an executable program though.

---

As I´d wanted to compile the same program with a C++ compiler, he/it threw an error:

```
 error: ‘main()::type::type’ has the same name as the class in which it is declared
```

So the question is for C, not for C++.

---

- Can I do so, without causing any further and deeper problems with my program?
- Am I might crossing into Undefined or Unspecified Behavior with this technique?
- Is there any reason to not do so (f.e. issues by the compilation/performance)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming what you tried were possible, what size would you expect that struct to have?

Comment: How about you try to compute the size of `type` by yourself?

Comment: @Yunnosch I didn´t thought about the size as such crucial part. But for the moment, let´s assume the size of the provided structure.

Comment: Better use structure pointers, you can change your declaration of the structure to `typedef struct type {char name[20], address[50]; struct type *next} type_t;`

Comment: Which size would you assume for a structure which has about 55 bytes per level and an indeterminate and unlimited number of levels?

Comment: How would you access the `name` member of the deepest level? (This is a trick question, you first need to determine the deepest level. Can you?)

Comment: @Yunnosch I think there is misunderstanding in my thoughts of the topic, but this is exactly for what I´ve asked the question. Aside. 1. I´ve thought the size is be able to determined by the provided code and might be stop at certain level. Can this crash the computer at where it is executed? I now think, yes. But why are then recursive datastructures available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To begin with, `struct type;` is a forward declaration, not a member variable definition. Secondly, no you can't do it, you need to use pointers.

To use a structure it must be fully defined, the definition have to end (with the closing `}`) before it can be used. Otherwise the compiler doesn't know the full size of the structure and don't know how big it is and how must memory to reserve for instances of the structure.

But to create a pointer to a structure, all the compiler needs to know is the structure tag (`type` in your case). That's because the size of a pointer is know at compile-time. The size of the full structure itself doesn't need to be known at that point.

Comment: My thought was (which seems to be wrong now), that the compiler treats the instance of `struct type` inside its own structure as replication of its "mother" and I do not need to declare and define it a second time.

Comment: Well you've not given the field of that type an identifier, even ignoring the fact that this attempts to construct an infinitely sized type.